# Cannot remove "Continue Reading" when displaying posts

Tags: php, wordpress

i have created custom button "Read More", but in the posts, "Continue Reading" link appears and don't know how to fix it. I've tried to use

```
function wpsites_read_more_link() {
    return '<a class="more-link" href="' . get_permalink() . '"></a>';
}
add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'wpsites_read_more_link' );
```

Here's my if statement

```
if( $excerpt=='true' ) {
        if( $readmore=='true' ) {
                echo get_the_excerpt()."<a href='".get_permalink($article_id)."'><button>Read More</button></a>";
        } else {
            the_content();
        }
    }
```

Into my shordcode file, but that's not fixing the problem. Why ?

Comment: In your `if` statements you check whether `$excerpt` and `$readmore` are equal to `"true"` as a string. Are those variables strings?

Comment: Yes, the variables are strings

Answer (score 0):

Check below scenarios, 
1. If implement by custom template, Check that template file have "Continue Reading” link.
2. Or default archive template used means check archive.php file have "Continue Reading” link.
3. If it is custom post type means check post_type-archive.php file have "Continue Reading” link.
4. Have any plugin automatically add read more link button in archive post, So check by de-activate all plugin and check.

Comment: I'have created a custom plugin, which have "Read More" button functionality and i want to remove "Continue Reading"

Comment: Then remove default "Continue Reading" in above mentioned .php file

Comment: First remove default in used in theme then you can do anything you want in plugin

Comment: Bro im trying to create a plugin. Is it good practice to say to users to change their files ??

Comment: Some theme custom values or template variables you can't override by plugin or hook.

Comment: it's not helpfull.